# Struggling with apollo-link-ws x-api-key authorization

Tags: websocket, apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I'm using Apollo to connect to an AWS Appsync API which is secured with an API Key. No problems with queries and mutations over http but I'm on unfamiliar territory using websockets for subscriptions.

Using apollo-link-ws I have the following, and I have no idea how to add the API Key. Can any kind soul offer advice?

```
const ws = new WebSocketLink({
      uri: `wss://xxxxx.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/graphql`,
      options: {
        reconnect: true
      }
    });
```

BTW I'm assuming that the url for wss is the same as for http....

Comment: This won't work. GraphQL leaves subscription transport up to the implementation, as such it's not defined in the spec and the WSS Link you defined in your code above is just going to fail because the handshake needed for authorization in AppSync hasn't taken place. Highly suggest you use the AppSync SDK or reverse engineer it's connection handshake as the code is OSS.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that’s the answer I’m looking for!

Answer (score 2):

`apollo-ws-link` does not directly work with AWS AppSync subscriptions. Take a look at the [AWS Amplify GraphQL client](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/api_guide#working-with-graphql-endpoints) that handles authorization with AppSync as well as subscriptions. This should get your app working with AppSync in a couple minutes.

If you want to implement your own subscriptions client, the handshake is documented within the [Amplify library](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/packages/aws-amplify/src/API/API.ts#L418).

Comment: Thanks but it has to be Apollo. I want a setup that will eventually be agnostic about the backend. My question is how to add API Key authorisation to Apollo-ws-link.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization is usually based on connectionParams, but AWS decided to go different way, and they implemented it [some shady way](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/api/src/API.ts#L429) using REST and custom headers.

The problem is Websockets [doesn't support custom headers](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3062#issuecomment-332065429). What makes it difficult to integrate with Apollo.

AppSync has much more flaws than just this one. I wouldn't recommend it for anything more ambitious than a blog or chat anyway. [This article](https://medium.com/@dadc/aws-appsync-the-unexpected-a430ff7180a3) explain better some of its drawbacks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out the AppSync guide for "Building a JavaScript Client App": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-javascript.html

With AWSAppSyncClient setting up subscriptions is effortless. It uses websockets automatically when setting up subscriptions.

I haven't even been aware of apollo-link-ws and such complexities when using AppSync subscriptions with Apollo. I only have experience of AppSync subscriptions with the React client but the plain JavaScript usage seems comparatively simple.

From the example in the guide:

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: url,
    region: region,
    auth: {
        type: type,
        credentials: credentials,
    }
});

client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
    //Now subscribe to results
    const observable = client.subscribe({ query: subquery });

    const realtimeResults = function realtimeResults(data) {
        console.log('realtime data: ', data);
    };

    observable.subscribe({
        next: realtimeResults,
        complete: console.log,
        error: console.log,
    });
});

// Set up a subscription query
const subquery = gql(`
subscription NewPostSub {
newPost {
    __typename
    id
    title
    author
    version
}
}`);
```

For Node.js usage, the guide also shows how to set up global.WebSocket and such dependencies in the example code.

Comment: Please see my earlier comment. This is a question about Apollo. All I’m looking for is an example of adding an API key. I’m not interested in Appsync because I want to be able to work with other back ends.

Comment: @Kwoxford Yes I saw your earlier comment and using AWSAppSyncClient over Amplify should allow you to have a great deal more control. Using other backends than AppSync not something that was clearly mentioned. Anyhow you might consider creating an interface and using AWSAppSyncClient under the hood but there might be a simpler way. Please stop downvoting answers that are wrong when the reason for that is an unclear question. For the record, the question has been downvoted for not being clear.

Comment: It seems clear to me. “I have no idea how to add the API Key.”  I also said  “I’m not interested in Appsync because I want to be able to work with other back ends”. What’s unclear about that? I don’t understand why people are challenging the question rather than answering it.